# Regex that allows spaces, hyphens, apostrophe, period, upper and lower case characters but cannot be a blank string

Tags: regex

I would like a string like `Brandon's Test-Name.` to pass.

The current attempt passes for the sample string. But it also passes blank space which I don't want.

```
regex = /[^a-zA-Z.'\- ]/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that you negated all listed symbols and characters. You should use

```
/^[a-zA-Z.'\- ]+$/
```

##### JavaScript Example

```
let string = "Brandon's Test-Name.";

console.log(!!string.match(/^[a-zA-Z.'\- ]+$/))  // true
```

Also, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ93Oy/1)